# How to add different models to only one model in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have some models that are used to make one order per dining table. My goal is to have different dining tables, these always have a total order and the total order has individual orders.

I have difficulties when i create a second dining table, with a second total order, to avoid taking orders (relationship) from the first table.

How can i make a total order that has his own orders, without any relationships from other orders?

Here my models:

```py
class Order(models.Model):
    Beer = models.ForeignKey(Beer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='beer')
    SoftDrink = models.ForeignKey(SoftDrink, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='soft_drink')
    ForeignBeer = models.ForeignKey(ForeignBeer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True,
                                    related_name='foreign_beer')
    Liquor = models.ForeignKey(Liquor, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='liquor')
    Wine = models.ForeignKey(Wine, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='wine')
    BarDrink = models.ForeignKey(BarDrink, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='bar_drink')
    Meal = models.ForeignKey(Meal, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='meal')


class TotalOrder(models.Model):
    Order = models.ManyToManyField(Order, related_name='order')
    Total_Price = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)


class Table(models.Model):
    Number = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    Total_Order = models.ForeignKey(TotalOrder, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='total_order', blank=True,
                                    null=True)
```

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding of your data model is correct, your relationships are backwards.

If one `TotalOrder` belongs to one `Table`, the `ForeignKey` should be defined on the `TotalOrder` model. The same applies to the `Order` model.

On a somewhat unrelated note, the common convention is that class attributes are written in lower case (e.g. `Table.number`, not `Table.Number`)

Comment: Yeah :D thanks. I switched the relationships. Now it works.